# ROS Qt creator GUI

Tags: ros, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone,
I am a freshman on ROS and Qt. Sorry to post long question in next, I am overwhelming by incorporate Qt GUI in ROS for almost 4 days, I follow the former posts, [post1](http://answers.ros.org/question/2626/setting-up-qt-creator-for-ros), and [post2](http://answers.ros.org/question/676/qt-creator-and-ros) and their related links, and thanks for their answers, I could use Qt creator to compile the ROS packages. However, when I try to bind the Qt program to ROS program, I do not find way to do, (mainly on the CMakeList.txt ). So next is my question: I want to build a simple interface to play with the turtle in learning_joy package instead of using joystick.

1. According to the tutorials on joystick, I could control the turtle with
   my joystick. So I use the CMakeList.txt as the copy to add some Qt creator CMake
   inside. The original learing_joy CMakeList.txt is

   ```
       cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
       include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

       #set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

       rosbuild_init()

        #set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
        set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
            #set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
            set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

        # Set the example from the Qt

        #uncomment if you have defined messages
        rosbuild_genmsg()
        #uncomment if you have defined services
        #rosbuild_gensrv()

        #common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
        #rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
            #target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
        #rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
        #rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
            #rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp)
            rosbuild_add_executable(turtle_teleop_joy  src/teleop_turtle_joy.cpp)
            #target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME})
   ```
2. By searching CMake and Qt example, I find one example "HelloworldQt",
   which includes 5 files: HelloWidget.cpp, HelloWidget.h, Mainwindow.cpp, MainWindow.h,
   and main.cpp, I also ran this Qt project on my Qt creator,

it's CMakeList.txt is"

```
        CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
         PROJECT(HelloWorldQt)

        SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
        SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")

        # QT4 Handling
        FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)

        INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})

         SET( HWQ_Qt4_SRC
                 src/MainWindow.h
                 src/HelloWidget.h
           )
         SET( HWQ_Qt4_UI
            )
         SET( HWQ_Qt4_RES
             )

         QT4_WRAP_CPP(HWQ_MOC_CPP ${HWQ_Qt4_SRC})
         QT4_WRAP_UI(HWQ_UI_CPP ${HWQ_Qt4_UI})
         QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(HWQ_RES_H ${HWQ_Qt4_RES})

         INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( . )

         # General
         SET( HWQ_SRC
              src/main.cpp
              src/MainWindow.cpp
              src/HelloWidget.cpp
              ${HWQ_MOC_CPP}
              ${HWQ_UI_CPP}
              ${HWQ_RES_H}
            )

      SET( HWQ_LIB
             ${QT_LIBRARIES}
          )

        ADD_EXECUTABLE(HelloWorldQt ${HWQ_SRC} )
        TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(HelloWorldQt ${HWQ_LIB} )

        INSTALL_TARGETS( /bin HelloWorldQt)"
```

3. So I want to incorporate these two files as one, and combine the main.cpp and add
   #include <QtGui/QApplication>
   #include "MainWindow.h"
   #include 
   #include 
   #include 
   in teleop_turtle_joy.cpp, but I find no matter what sequences I put these CMakeLists files,  it can run CMake, but when I build, Qt creator show "
   ***error: undefined reference to `QMainWindow::QMainWindow(QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>); error: undefined reference to` vtable for MainWindow"*** and etc,

For the second kind of error, it because lacking moc files, so my incorporated cMakeList does not produce moc files, but why?
It looks that combined CMakeList.txt really run on the ROS, but it does not produce the same file as when I only run HelloWidget, which produces the moc files for two **.cpp. So can you point one or more direction for me?

the corporated CMakeList.txt "

```
        cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
        PROJECT(learning_joy)

        # Set the build type.  Options are:
        #  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
        #  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
        #  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
        #  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
        #  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
        #set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

       #  add from Qt
        SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
        SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")

       # Set the example from the Qt
         FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)

         INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})

         SET( HWQ_Qt4_SRC
                    src/MainWindow.h
                    src/HelloWidget.h
                )

        MESSAGE(STATUS "step1.")

               SET( HWQ_Qt4_UI
                    )
               SET( HWQ_Qt4_RES
                    )

          QT4_WRAP_CPP(HWQ_MOC_CPP ${HWQ_Qt4_SRC})
          QT4_WRAP_UI(HWQ_UI_CPP ${HWQ_Qt4_UI})
          QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(HWQ_RES_H ${HWQ_Qt4_RES})

          MESSAGE(STATUS "step2.")

          INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( . )

        SET( HWQ_SRC
                 src/MainWindow.cpp
                 src/HelloWidget.cpp
                 src/teleop_turtle_joy.cpp
                  ${HWQ_MOC_CPP}
                  ${HWQ_UI_CPP}
                  ${HWQ_RES_H}
               )

          MESSAGE(STATUS "step3.")

          SET( HWQ_LIB
                ${QT_LIBRARIES}
               )

            ADD_EXECUTABLE(turtle_teleop_joy1  ${HWQ_SRC} )
            TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(turtle_teleop_joy1 ${HWQ_LIB} )
            INSTALL_TARGETS( /bin turtle_teleop_joy1)

            include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
            rosbuild_init()

             MESSAGE(STATUS "step4.")

             #set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
             set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
              #set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
             set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

             #uncomment if you have defined messages
              rosbuild_genmsg()
             #uncomment if you have defined services
             #rosbuild_gensrv()

              MESSAGE(STATUS "step5.")

             #common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
             #rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
             #target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
             #rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp)
              rosbuild_add_executable(turtle_teleop_joy  src/teleop_turtle_joy.cpp)

             # Qt add

             MESSAGE(STATUS "step6.")"

   Sorry to put this long question, I really appreciate someone could help me for 
 this Makefile problem. Thanks in advance!!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12790/ros-qt-creator-gui/) by [tairen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1618/tairen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-01-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That looks quite chaotic. Actually it shouldn't be so hard.

First: You need to start from the ROS side, i.e. create a normal non-qt ROS package first.

Now you only need some minor tweaks to the CMakeLists.txt.

After rosbuilt_init() I usually put:

```
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
# enable/disable some Qt features
set( QT_USE_QTGUI TRUE )
set( QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE )
set( QT_USE_QTXML TRUE )
include(${QT_USE_FILE})

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)
```

Qt specific files might need to be moc'd. This includes the headers, so put those here:

```
set(qt_srcs
      src/qtfile.cpp)
set(qt_hdrs
      src/qtfile.h)
qt4_automoc(${qt_srcs})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(qt_moc_srcs ${qt_hdrs})
```

Finally GUI files (.ui) might need to be processed:

```
QT4_WRAP_UI(uis_h src/qtfile.ui)
# include this for ui_h
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})</pre>
When you actually build the executable, make sure you include the files processed above:
<pre>rosbuild_add_executable(qttest src/myMain.cpp
${uis_h} ${qt_srcs} ${qt_moc_srcs})
target_link_libraries(qttest ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-08-04**:
That "Actually it shouldn't be so hard" is so reassuring !

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [qt_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/qt_ros) stack has some simple support and [example packages](http://www.ros.org/wiki/qt_tutorials) for qt-ros development. Also [qt_create](http://www.ros.org/wiki/qt_create) has a python script (ala roscreate-pkg style) that will build you a working qt-ros package immediately and you can extend from there.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2012-01-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tairen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1618/tairen/) on 2012-01-29**:
roscreate-qt-pkg commands not find, :-), actually is my fault. But be careful, when I install correctly, I can't type other commands, like ls, sudo, maybe in embeded edition does not have this commands, so I go to ubuntu recover mode to delete the "export PATH...." , so my system is going well.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2012-01-28**:
What error are you getting? Do you really have a '' in the "...:\${PATH}" above?

**Comment by [tairen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1618/tairen/) on 2012-01-28**:
I will try when I install the electric. I have install the eros stack on my diamondback version, but I can not run command:roscreate-qt-pkg qtest on my diamondback, even I add the " export PATH=`rospack find eros_python_tools`/scripts:\${PATH} " to setup.sh,  so I post my first question.thanks!